# Python-Extract data from text rows

Tags: python-2.7

I have following input from a webpage. And this is expected to have many rows, present in [] starting from {"EffectiveTime" ... to "SystemLoad"} I want to extract the values from all these tags... Can anyone suggest the right way to do this? There are so many rows and its recurring.

```
{"Debug":"Key:01-Oct-2016 04:00:00_04-Dec-2016 23:45:00,
Age:-1","ErrorMessage":null,"LastUpdated":"06-Dec-2016 15:14:14","Rows":
[{"EffectiveTime":"01-Oct-2016 
04:00:00","EurPrice":30.460,"GbpPrice":26.260,"RunType":"EP2","SystemLoad":2702.
651},{"EffectiveTime":"01-Oct-2016 
04:30:00","EurPrice":30.460,"GbpPrice":26.260,"RunType":"EP2","SystemLoad":2694.
620},{"EffectiveTime":"01-Oct-2016 
05:00:00","EurPrice":30.510,"GbpPrice":26.300,"RunType":"EP2","SystemLoad":2718.
430},
```

Comment: How to apply it to all the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define the input string starting from the `[]` chars (skipping the debug part)

It's directly json data: unserializes into a list of python dictionaries

```
import json

text='''[{"EffectiveTime":"01-Oct-2016 04:00:00","EurPrice":30.460,"GbpPrice":26.260,
    "RunType":"EP2","SystemLoad":2702.651},{"EffectiveTime":"01-Oct-2016 04:30:00","EurPrice":30.460,"GbpPrice":26.260,"RunType":"EP2",
      "SystemLoad":2694.620},{"EffectiveTime":"01-Oct-2016 05:00:00","EurPrice":30.510,"GbpPrice":26.300,"RunType":"EP2","SystemLoad":2718.430}]'''

dict_list = json.loads(text)
for d in dict_list:
    print(d)
```

result:

```
{u'GbpPrice': 26.26, u'EffectiveTime': u'01-Oct-2016 04:00:00', u'EurPrice': 30.46, u'SystemLoad': 2702.651, u'RunType': u'EP2'}
{u'GbpPrice': 26.26, u'EffectiveTime': u'01-Oct-2016 04:30:00', u'EurPrice': 30.46, u'SystemLoad': 2694.62, u'RunType': u'EP2'}
{u'GbpPrice': 26.3, u'EffectiveTime': u'01-Oct-2016 05:00:00', u'EurPrice': 30.51, u'SystemLoad': 2718.43, u'RunType': u'EP2'}
```

The same result can be obtained with the full dump (including debug header) like this:

```
import json

text='''{"Debug":"Key:01-Oct-2016 04:00:00_04-Dec-2016 23:45:00,Age:-1","ErrorMessage":null,"LastUpdated":"06-Dec-2016 15:14:14","Rows":
[{"EffectiveTime":"01-Oct-2016 04:00:00","EurPrice":30.460,"GbpPrice":26.260,"RunType":"EP2","SystemLoad":2702.651},
{"EffectiveTime":"01-Oct-2016 04:30:00","EurPrice":30.460,"GbpPrice":26.260,"RunType":"EP2","SystemLoad":2694.620},{"EffectiveTime":"01-Oct-2016 05:00:00","EurPrice":30.510,"GbpPrice":26.300,"RunType":"EP2","SystemLoad":2718.430}]}'''

main_dict = json.loads(text)
for d in main_dict["Rows"]:  # access "Rows" member
    print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!